# How to solve the IOError[errno 17] file exists when opening a file?

Tags: python, aix

I try to open a file for writing using the following:

```
fh = open("testfile", "w")
```

But, I get an exception:

> IOError: [Errno 17] File exists!

I have write permissions and there is no race condition. Does anyone know why I get the error?

Thanks.

Comment: This is really an OS error, so you should mention your OS and anything possibly unusual? Is it a network share? Removable disk? etc.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317389/python-exception-errno-17-file-exists-using-open-on-windows

Comment: what happens if you try to open the file in append mode?

Comment: It doesn't have an answer because it isn't a Python problem. It's a Windows exclusive file access problem and it has no reliable solution.

Comment: @msw, This error can happen if unix/linux if the existing "file" is a directory or special file. I guess you are saying it's possible to see it on Windows even if the existing file is a regular file. Do you have a link to more information about this?

Comment: I use AIX operating system. The file does exist. It is ok if I open it with 'r+'.

Comment: It is a status file, I update this file muultiple times in my program using the same file writting method. Sometimes, it is successful, sometimes it fails at the file open.

Comment: Why "file exists" is an error? It should be ok if the file exists.

Comment: `fopen()` should never return `EEXIST` according to [the man page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.basetechref%2Fdoc%2Fbasetrf1%2Ffopen.htm)...

Comment: If we use "wx" option and the file exists, then it will return "file exists" error.

Comment: I tried to use "w+" option, and it works. Not sure the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The `wx` mode is something [new in Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open), and is documented to raise an error if the file already exists. If `w+` mode is working, it seems to me that the code published in the question is not really in line with the error returned...